# Find Max indices of 2d numpy array

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, indexing

I have this matlab code which aims to find the index with max value across each column of a 2-dimensional matrix.

```
    [~, indk] = max(R2)
```

I would like to apply this in python but cannot seem to find any good approaches.

In my case the variable R2 is a 18x122880 matrix. I would like indk to be a 1x122880 array.

I started by doing this:

```
        indk = np.argmax(R2)
```

but this just got me one index out. Is there any way to approach this like the MATLAB code did?

Answer (score 0):

[numpy.ndarray.argmax](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html#numpy-argmax)

```
import numpy

arr = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[6,5,4],[7,8,9]])

print(arr.argmax(axis = 1)) # [2 0 2]
print(arr.argmax(axis = 0)) # [2 2 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to this

`R2.argmax(axis=0)` #or 1 depending on what axis you want

Answer (score 0):

```
indk = np.argmax(R2, axis=0)
```

`axis=0`  represents the columns of the matrix.